# Convert timezone of datetimes in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, timezone

So I've been trying to write a small script to convert a column of datetime values (coming from various timezones) to the same one.

```py
    datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
    for column in time_columns:
        df[column] = pd.to_datetime(df[column],format=datetime_format).dt.tz_convert("ETC/GMT+1").round('10ms')
```

I've tried this, and it results in the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert tz-naive timestamps, use tz_localize to localize
```

So then I've tried to use *tz_localize* instead, which results in:

```
TypeError: Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert.
```

It feels like a chicken and the egg, or a "catch 22" problem...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is is possible that your column contains some times which include a timezone and some which do not?

Comment: Better provide a [mre] of the data for clarity